I want to ban admin for edit or delete user fields
class BandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
readonly_fields = ('user',)
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
readonly_fields = ('user',)
class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
readonly_fields = ('user',)
I write this code on admin.py but admin can edit user data. How can I do in order to not allow him to edit user fields?

The customizations made in admin.py aim to enhance the usability of the Django admin interface, presenting the database in a more user-friendly manner. The superuser retains full control over the data, possessing the authority to modify any aspect within the system. Staff users can be assigned tailored permissions, ensuring that access is granted only to the necessary functionalities like read, add, delete on user permissions.

Then in admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Band, Album, Song

class ReadOnlyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('user',)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change and 'user' in form.changed_data:
            obj.user = getattr(obj, 'user', None)
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Band, ReadOnlyUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Album, ReadOnlyUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Song, ReadOnlyUserAdmin)

Hope this works!

Thanks but I did it with list_display, list_filter and has_permissions and it works

Assuming you have model name Band.
You can override form using following code and achieve your desired result.
I have given example for Band Model, you can use this concept for rest of your models.
from django import forms

class BandModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["user"].disabled = True
        self.fields["user"].widget.can_change_related = False

    class Meta:
        model = Band  # Model Name
        fields = "__all__"


class BandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BandModelForm

